# PrismTabbedPage created dynamicly with each tab having its own parameters

Tags: xamarin.forms, parameters, prism, tabbedpage

I'm setting up a PrismTabbedPage dynamically in Xamarin.Forms. I have a content page **PrismContentPageProfile** which shows the profile of a given Id. The Id I want to pass with a parameter. Problem is that each initialize is having all the parameters.

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/PrismTabbedPage1?createTab=PrismContentPageProfile?Id=Michel&createTab=PrismContentPageProfile?Id=Erik");
```

I expect to tabs. One for the profileId Michel and one for Erik. Problem is that the paramters in the Initialize look like this on each page:

```
{?createTab=PrismContentPageProfile%3FId%3DMichel&createTab=PrismContentPageProfile%3FId%3DErik}
```

As I don't know which tab I am, I don't know which profile to load.

I hoped that calling:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/PrismTabbedPage1?createTab=PrismContentPageProfile?Id=Michel&createTab=PrismContentPageProfile?Id=Erik");
```

would result in different parameters on each page. Id=Michel on the first page, Id=Erik on the second.

Or, if that is not possible, that I know which tab index I am. Then I can read the related parameter.

Comment: `each initialize is having all the parameters` - why not navigate two times independently, each time with the parameters for _one_ tab?

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Comment: like two calls to `NavigateAsync`